# Alert Dialog cancelling out itself

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have an `alert-dialog` which is displayed when the `fragment` is created, and only ONCE. Therefor, I have a preference which saves a `Boolean`. After the `alert-dialog` is displayed once, it shouldn't be displayed the next time the fragment is loaded. But, when loading the `fragment`, nothing happens. The alertdialog just doesn't appear. That being strange enough, it actually is working if I don't save the `Boolean` as true in the `shared-preferences`. Thus, I conclude, that somehow after trying to display the alertdialog, the preference is set to true and.... the alertdialog isn't being displayed? Why?

Here are is the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, Viewgroup container, Bundle savedINstanceState) {
    //here I am getting the default preference, it is set to false by default
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    tutorialtrue = pref.getBoolean("TutorialShownPref", false);
    if (!tutorialtrue) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Tutorial")
            .setMessage(R.string.notificationcont)
            .setPositiveButton("Verstanden", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

        AlertDialog tutdia = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        String i = "Log recieved";
        Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);
        tutdia.show();
        //this is the part for changing the preference to true
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("TutorialShownPref", true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

Also, the preference xml part, just in case:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="TutorialShownPref"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: When you say "notification" are you still speaking about the "dialog"? Those are two different things in Android and it looks like you're creating confusion by using them interchangeably. And regarding your problem, you show the dialog once, then you reload the fragment and it's not shown - and you ask why? Isn't it supposed to be the expected behavior? At least this is how I understand your question.

Comment: what should be the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, I somehow kept writing with "notification" in mind, but of course I meant the AlertDialog. And no, the problem was that the alertdialog wasn't being displayed the first time the fragment was loaded. But, I just put the saving of the boolean in my onClick Method, which basically does the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
editor.putBoolean("TutorialShownPref", true);
This will never false again. So your condition will not satisfy again.
```

Update preference false in `onDetach()` method of fragment